# jQueryMobile support for different resolutions

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I use jQueryMobile for an app to work on iPhone/Android devices. App has some custom images. How can I handle different resolutions? Should I include multiple versions of a image? and how to handle this in html5

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Look at running media queries documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/mediahelpers.html